# Re-purpose Sandwich Cookies

Tags: cookies

I am trying to find a recipe to re-purpose black and white sandwich cookies with the icing inside.

I have two bags my family will not eat; I would hate to waste them.

Comment: Welcome to CookingSE!  If you have a moment, please view our [tour] and [help]. Have fun!

Comment: Eat them yourself ? or make https://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2012/08/chocolate-oreo-cake-recipe.html

Answer (score 2):

If they are crunchy cookies with a fatty icing, you can probably smash them up (to crumbs), fatty component and all, and make a crust out of them for some kind of cream-pie or cheesecake. Sort of like a chocolatey "graham cracker" crust. Not clear on the exact composition of your cookies, but this works perfectly with "Oreo"-type cookies. If you make crumbs out of the whole cookies, you don't need to add any other ingredients to a pie crust. If your cookies are less sweet, or more sweet, or less fatty, etc. you might need to tweak the "recipe" a little, but I think you could work something out.

On the other hand, if your family don't like the cookies, they may not care for stuff made out of them either. Maybe you should give them to a neighbor, or local food-bank.

Answer (score 1):

I open them up, scoop out 1/2 the cream and replace it with peanut butter.

Comment: This sounds so good...